# using jquery to programme a back/previous button in a dynamic quiz app

Tags: jquery

Am trying to build a dynamic quiz that allows me use the previous/ back button to allow me make changes to my option but couldnot achieve it.Only the next button seems to be working fine.Please I need a jquery approach to solve this and also to get the final score.Thanks

Comment: Submit some of your code for review. This is the only way users can help you find your error.

Comment: @Enkode, am pasting the codes right away.Thanks